# Inserting product into table without inner select

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am filling a table with Area permissions for Users, but initially every User will be allowed to access every Area, so if I have 100 Users and 10 Areas there will be 1000 records in my UserAreas table.

```
UserAreasID UserID AreaID
=========== ====== ======
```

How can I do this in SQL Server 2005 given that I can't use in-line SELECTs?

Comment: what do you mean you *can't use in-line SELECTS*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [cross join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) should do it:

```
insert UserAreas (UserId, AreaId)
select u.UserId, a.AreaId
from [User] u
cross join Area a
```